# Count instances of string in separate dataframe, not exact match, using Python, pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, contains

I have a list of names in df1 and I need to see if they match anywhere in df2.
I know I probably need to use str.contains on each item and add one to a count, but I haven't figured out how to do this successfully.

```
for e in df2['People_separate']:
count = df1['People'].str.contains(e)
if count == True:
    count += 1
return count
```

example:
df1:

```
| People    | 
| --------  | 
| A B / E F | 
| A B / C D | 
| E F       |
```

df2 (looking to populate the 'counts' column:

```
| People_separate | Counts |
| --------------- | -------------|
| A B             | 2            |
| C D             | 1            |
| E F             | 2            |
```

Answer (score 1):

You can split the rows by ' / ' with `split`, then `explode` to convert lists into rows, and then count values with `value_counts`:

```
df['People'].str.split(' / ').explode().value_counts()
```

Output:

```
A B    2
E F    2
C D    1
```

Answer (score 1):

If the "not exact match" is really a requirement, then we form a search pattern to use with `Series.str.extractall`, and  take the value_counts of that extraction. This way if your search word is `'foo'` a word like `'foobar'` will still count as a match (because it contains `'foo'`).

The `reindex` ensures the resulting Series also shows 0s for words that never matched.

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame({"People": ['A B / E F', 'A B / C D', 'E F']})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({"People_separate": ['A B', 'C D', 'E F', 'banana']})
```

---

```
pat = '(' + '|'.join(df2['People_separate']) + ')'
#(A B|C D|E F)

(df1['People'].str.extractall(pat)[0]
   .value_counts()
   .reindex(df2['People_separate'], fill_value=0))
```

---

```
People_separate
A B       2
C D       1
E F       2
banana    0
Name: 0, dtype: int64
```